# How to create a Child Page via Confluence REST API with only Parent Page Title

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I'm trying to use the "Send web request" option in JIRA's Project Automation to generate a Confluence Page via REST API.

I'm able to use the following code but I don't know how to force Confluence to create a child page under a Parent Page for which I will only have the Parent Page Title available.

Since I've already automated the process of generating the parent pages, and the child page is to be generated based on a certain status, I will not know the Parent Page ID.

Can someone let me know how I can get the Parent Page ID from the Parent Page Title or generate the child page with just the Page Title?

The Custom Data looks like this:

```
{
"title": "Child Page",
"type": "page",
"space": { "key": "ABC" },
"status": "current",
"body": {"storage": {"value": "Sample Text", "representation": "storage"}}
}
```

P.S. I'm not a coder, so I would love some tips too.

Answer (score 0):

Here the way how you can found `Page ID` :

https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/confluence-rest-api-examples/

section
`Find a page by title and space key`

```
curl -u admin:admin -X GET "http://localhost:8080/confluence/rest/api/content?title=myPage%20Title
&spaceKey=TST&expand=history" | python -mjson.tool
```